# Темпоральность и категория времени

Tags: лексика

Категория темпоральности это и есть категория времени, или категория времени одна из ветвей категории темпоральности?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке нет грамматической категории темпоральности, а другие, не грамматические, категории мы тут обычно не рассматриваем.

Если же Ваш вопрос чисто терминологического или системологического  плана, то в принципе можно и подумать, но хотелось бы сначала узнать, из какой это вообще дисциплины.  Если что-то чисто литературоведческое, то там нет понятия "категории времени". Получается, эти вещи просто несопоставимы, поскольку относятся к разным научным дисциплинам.

Answer (score 0):

Категория темпоральности - более широкое понятие, чем категория времени. Темпоральность – это семантическая категория, которая служит для обозначения времени описываемой ситуации по отношению к какой-либо точке отсчета, чаще всего – по отношению к моменту речи говорящего, т.е. к тому моменту, в который произносится предложение. Грамматическая же категория времени, в основу которой ставят сложную систему временных форм глагола, является частью категории темпоральности.Иначе говоря, темпоральность выражается обычно морфологической категорией времени.